# how to add element in XML Message using Stophe

Tags: javascript, xml, xmpp, strophe

I am using [Strophe JS](http://strophe.im/strophejs/doc/1.1.3/files/strophe-js.html)

I want to add element inside the message xml tag.

The Strophe Link : http://strophe.im/strophejs/doc/1.1.3/files/strophe-js.html

My code is  :

```
connection.sendIQ($iq({type: "get"}).c("query", {xmlns: Strophe.NS.ROSTER}).tree(), onRoster);
connection.send(
                $msg(
                      {
                        to:"user1@rtm.umobility.bizrtc/primea",
                        id:"user2_1564828681632",
                        from:"user2@rtm.umobility.bizrtc/primea",
                      }
                   )

                );
```

This generates the following XML :

```
<message from="user2@rtm.umobility.bizrtc/primea" id="user2_1564828681632" to="user1@rtm.umobility.bizrtc/primea" xmlns="jabber:client"/>
```

I need something like this :

```
<message xmlns:cli="jabber:client" to="cinu@rtm.umobility.bizrtc" cli:subject="TEXT MESSAGE" cli:lang="en" type="chat" id="rajan_1564637142811" from="rajan@rtm.umobility.bizrtc/primea"><body>Some XMPP Message</body><request xmlns="urn:xmpp:receipts"></request></message>
```

In above XML it has `<body>` tag inside the `<message>` tag. How do i do this ? I want to do thing using Stophe JS. To Send XMPP message.